# Unable to send pdf through binary with UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, binaryfiles

I am having some trouble sending a pdf file from a client to the server by reading the file in binary. I am using a UDP transfer and when I send a text file from client to server I receive the file completely without any errors however when I send a PDF I get an error opening the file. Heres what I have for both the sender and receiver:

Sender:

```
file = fopen(file_name_char, "rb"); //read in binary here

int size_count = (file_size / (BUFFER_SIZE - 2)) + 1; //amount of times to loop

            for (int i = 0; i < size_count; i++)
            {
                memset(szbuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                fread(szbuffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE - 2, file); //Read for the buffersize -2 (reserve a spot for bit and \0)

                strcpy(szbuffer, concat(current_bit, szbuffer));

                send_with_select(s, szbuffer, (struct sockaddr*)&sa1, (struct sockaddr*)&sa1, sa1_length, current_bit, "file contents", 0); //send file contents

                file_size = file_size - BUFFER_SIZE + 2; //decrease size

                client_bit = change_bit(client_bit);
                *current_bit = bit_string(client_bit);
                //change bit
            }
            fclose(file);
```

For my UDP transfer I am prepending each buffer with a sequence number to simulate a Stop N Wait protocol

Receiver:

```
int size_count = (file_size / (BUFFER_SIZE - 2)) + 1; //amount of times to loop

            for (int i = 0; i < size_count; i++)
            {
                file = fopen(file_name, "ab"); 
                //open file for writing

                memset(szbuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                receive_packet_transfer(s, szbuffer, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_in, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_in, sa_length, current_bit, content, "file contents", client_bit); //receive file contents

                client_bit = change_bit(client_bit);
                *current_bit = bit_string(client_bit);
                //change bit

                if (file_size <= BUFFER_SIZE)
                    fwrite(content, sizeof(char), file_size, file);
                else
                    fwrite(content, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE - 2, file); //write into file

                file_size = file_size - BUFFER_SIZE + 2; //decrease size
                fclose(file);
            }
```

I have implemented send_with_select() and receive_packet_transfer() using the sendto() recvfrom() methods. They basically do the same thing but wait for an ACK or timeout (using select).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> strcpy(szbuffer, concat(current_bit, szbuffer));

String manipulation functions like `strcpy`, `strlen` etc work only with textual data which cannot contain `\0` by itself because they consider `\0` the end of the string. But PDF is binary and thus can contain `\0`. Thus `strcpy` will only copy the data up to the first `\0`.

Apart from that, using UDP to transfer files is a bad idea unless you make sure that you can deal with lost packets, duplicate packets and packet reordering. Better use TCP which already cares about all this.

Comment: Ulrich I need to use UDP for an assignment. Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Do u know if there is a method to copy in binary or should I use a struct to avoid trying to prepend the buffer with a sequence bit (in my situation)